# Update CSS Code on Scroll : Simplify so it doesn't use JQuery and just the simplest Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code (see below) - I am terrible with Javascript, I was hoping someone could help making this work WITHOUT using jquery.  If the same solution isn't possible then just a way to apply different CSS style to an item on scrolling past 300px. I have looked but Javascript and JQuery are alien to me...

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("scroll",function(){
            if($(document).scrollTop()>300){ 
                $("header").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
                }
            else{
                $("header").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
                }
            }); 
    </script>
</head>
```

A sample of what I want is here
http://www.goaoutreach.org/
The logo shrinks down when scrolling past the main image (or thereabouts).

Current CSS

```
small img{ width:50px; height:auto; top: -10px;  }
large img{ width:150px; height:auto; top: -10px; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why do you require pure javascript not jquery. You can change your code to pure javascript with this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   window.onscroll = function(){
       var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
       document.querySelector("header").setAttribute("class", (scrollTop>300)?"small":"large");
   }; 

</script>
```

Simple demo
http://jsfiddle.net/tintucraju/hLtyq3t1/

Comment: I just want to keep my site as 'lite' as possible and remove any calls to external files etc.